# How should pomegranates be stored?

Tags: storage-method, fruit, refrigerator, pomegranate

What is the proper way to store a pomegranate? How long can they be stored for at room temperature?

Would refrigerating pomegranates cause any problems (I'm a little worried about the fridge getting slightly to cold, freezing the seeds and ruining the fruit).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this page](http://homecooking.about.com/cs/foodfactsheets/p/pomegranate_pro.htm):

> Whole fruits can be stored **for a month in a cool, dry area**, or **refrigerated up to two months**. The seed pips can be frozen in an airtight bag up to one year. Fresh juice should be refrigerated and used within two to three days.

In my experience in a very dry climate (Colorado) after a couple weeks the skins become desiccated and very hard—you need to saw through them with a serrated knife—but the seeds are still mostly unaffected. They will shrink somewhat, but still remain unspoiled and flavorful.

However, if you refrigerate them, ensure that you do not let them get too cold. According to [this page](http://ucanr.edu/blogs/blogcore/postdetail.cfm?postnum=12491):

> *[…] exposure to temperatures **below 5°C (41°F) during storage** and transport for **longer than 4 weeks** is a major cause of deterioration […]*
>
> *The minimum safe storage temperature is **5°C (41°F) for up to 8 weeks**, if decay is not a problem. For longer storage, the temperature should be at 7°C (45°F) to avoid chilling injury, but decay […] and weight loss may become a limitation.*

[image: photo comparing effects of different temperatures and durations]

<sup>*Sorry that the photo is not better quality.*</sup>

Comment: 41℉ is considerably higher than the 35℉-37℉ I normally hear recommended for a refrigerator temperature. I guess refrigerating pomegranates is something you can only do if you have a spare refrigerator you can run at a higher temperature.